# No icon in the title in Windows 10

Tags: qt, icons, windows-10

In Windows 7 I haven't any problems with application icon. In Windows 10 no problem with icon of the executable file, but I have a problem with window icon. There is default icon instead of my icon in the caption.

This is how I set the icon

```
QIcon icon(":/icons/icon1.ico");
setWindowIcon(icon);
```

Copying `imageformats\qico.dll` to `.\imageformats\` did not help.

Comment: Do you rebuild your app on Windows 10, or is it the same executable file (i.e built on Win7 and copied on Windows 10) ?

Comment: Built on Win7. Do you think building on Win10 should help?

Comment: It could help if it is a deployment issue. Did you use `windeployqt` ? What you could do immediately is to add some debug output to see if it is a problem of loading the .ico file or setting the window icon. To check the validity of the QIcon, you can check the QPixmap returned by `icon.pixmap(32,32);`

Comment: I think the author ment same issue Im facing - the .exe icon is set correctly, but for me, when my program is working, I change between 10 icons making nice "animation" to show to user that Im bussy in the background. And this works perfectly fine on win7 and win vista, didnt test win8, but for sure dosent work on win10. Thats why all replies are irrevelant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try use RC file.

For example:

app.rc

```
IDI_ICON1   ICON DISCARDABLE "app_icon.ico"
```

And *.pro file:

```
win32 {
    RC_FILE += app.rc
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `QWidget::setWindowIcon()` function is only useful for setting the icon of a window. It has no effect on the binary file (.exe) icon.

The binary file icon is handled by Windows without running your program. So whatever you put in your code will not have any effect on the executable file icon.

Also moving `qico.dll` around will not have any effect here. This DLL is loaded by Qt when your program runs.

To change your executable icon, you have to embed it in the executable using Windows resource system (do not confuse it with Qt resource system). To do so when you have a qmake project you can either use `RC_ICONS`, `RC_FILE` or `RC_RES`.

The easiest way is to use `RC_ICONS`:

```
RC_ICONS = icons/appicon.ico # Path relative to the .pro file
```

Note that setting `RC_FILE` or `RC_RES` will disable `RC_ICONS`. Take a look at the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#rc-icons

It is also worth noting that Windows keeps a cache of icons, so if you change the icon and rebuild, the new icon may not appear immediately.

Comment: Actually I have a problem with a window icon. No problem with exe file icon. I edited my question.